# Not being able to access webapp from host in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a simple webproject which I want to "Dockerize" but I keep failing at exposing the webapp to host.
My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev curl && \
        pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app/web
```

And requirements.txt looks like:

```
PasteScript==2.0.2
Pylons==1.0.2
```

The web directory was built using:

```
paster create --template=pylons web
```

And finally start_server.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

paster serve --daemon development.ini start
```

Now I am able to build with :

```
docker build -t webapp .
```

And then run command:

```
docker run -it -p 5000:5000 --name app webapp:latest /bin/bash
```

And then inside the docker container I run:

```
bash start_server.sh
```

which successfully starts the webapp on port 5000 and if I curl inside docker container I get expected response. Also the container is up and running with the correct port mappings:

```
bc6511d584ae        webapp:latest       "/bin/bash"         2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes               0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   app
```

Now if I run docker port app it looks fine:

```
5000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:5000
```

However I cannot get any response from server from host with :

```
curl localhost:5000
```

I have probably misunderstood something here but it seems fine to me.

Comment: What's your host OS?

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your dockerfile you need to add `EXPOSE 5000` your port mapping is correct think of it as opening the port on your container and then you map it with localhost with the `-p`

Answer in the comment

> when you make_server bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost

Comment: Hi Hamuel, tried it and does not work. I added EXPOSE 5000 to Dockerfile and rebuilt exactly as above but still no reponse.

Comment: in your pylon code did you make_server did you bind the ip with localhost or 0.0.0.0 ??? if with localhost change it to 0.0.0.0